# Tool for synchronising database changes from development database to production?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-warehouse, production

This may be a pipe dream, but I'm hoping someone knows of a tool which can be configured to compare all or some (keys) of the data in two identical database and merge, perhaps based on relationships.

Specifically looking for one for SQL Server.

I'm not really asking for the best one, but if it exists it would be nice to hear how it is used.

Any other ideas for how to manage the work done or data added in dev and push it out to production without copying the entire database are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use this and personally think it's excellent.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

There is also another product for the schema side.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a specific tools but you can implement in your process of publications the analysis and executions of delta files, containing the diffs from one verision to another. Magento, Wordpress are using something like this for example. They have something like this

```
//sql_update_001_002.sql
UPDATE some_table...
DELETE some entries
CREATE a_new_table... 
// compere some keys or do other logic.
//etc
```

Then they have a script that analyses the current version and if needed it executes the corresponding sql.

Answer (score 2):

Navicat allows to make data and structure synchronization between 2 databases (also located on different servers).

Answer (score 2):

In terms of tools I agree with Chris - Redgate's toolset for both schema and data comparisons

If you are also thinking about your overall db dev process - then I have written a blog on the topic which might be of interest.

It also has some links to how others have tackled this subject.

http://michaelbaylon.wordpress.com/category/data-management/database-development/sql-script-management/